# R, improve loop, make embarrassingly parallel?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm relatively new to R, and I am writing very, very slow code. I have started looking into ideas like vectorization and embarrassingly parallel, but I need help in applying them. Here is the code I am writing, and my understanding of the problem I am facing:

```
for (k in 1:3) {

        for (i in 1:2) {
                p[i]<- sum(output[i,1:3]>=intv[k,1])/200
                                        }

        cp[k,1]<-crossprod(port,p)

                  }

Sample data:
intv<-array(c(1,5,15),c(3,1))
output<-array(c(5,10,15,20,25,30),c(2,3))
port<-array(c(1,2,3),c(3,1))


output is 16,384 rows by 200 columns in real data set
intv is 16,384 rows in real data set
```

Essentially, this is picking up a value from intv (which has 16,384 distinct values), and then going over each row in output to find the number of columns that have values greater than this value. And then with the next intv value, and so on.. until many, many, many hours have gone by.

Now here is my understanding of the problem:

I appreciate I have to pick up a value from intv from first row. 
But I don't know why I should go over each row in output sequentially to find the number of columns greater than this value.

UPDATE: I tried lapply and replaced the for loops, but the file size was too big, even on AWS. I tried the for loops instead and it took about 3.5 hours. I would really, realllly appreciate any ideas to speed this up.

Thank you!

Changing to matrix helped a lot:

```
> system.time({for (i in 1:nrow(facnahum)) {
+ probm[i,1]<- sum(outputm[i,1:200]>=intvm[k,1])/200
+ 
+ }
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.55    0.00    0.54 
> 
> 
> system.time({for (i in 1:length(facnahu$MDR)) {
+ prob[i]<- sum(output[i,1:200]>=intv[k,1])/200
+ 
+ }
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   1.62    0.00    1.62
```

Comment: By including example datasets you will greatly increase the probability of getting the answer.

Comment: intv has 16,384 rows of data, and output is 37,000 rows by 200 columns...

Comment: Just curious - Is `length(port$lr)` giving you the correct result? Do you mean `nrow(port$Ir)` ? Not related, but just curious.

Comment: i guess what im trying to do is apply the same sum function to each row in output, but then i don't know the syntax for that. i would appreciate help with that if that is the way to go. i hope that is specific. thanks for your interest.

Comment: hi maxpd, length seems to be fine.. nrow is probably the right thing to do though.

Comment: please add sample data..

Comment: hi, hope sample data helps?

Comment: hi, not sure if this sample data qualifies. please let me know what you are looking for exactly if not. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here are some quick and dirty first steps - i.e. an abstraction of how you can start vectorizing your problem, using just a bunch of random numbers.

```
set.seed(12) #for comparability set a seed 
Output <- matrix(sample(x=c(10:40),40, TRUE), ncol=5)
Intv <- matrix(1:16, ncol=1) 
l <- lapply(X=Intv, FUN=`<`, Output) #reverse your operator because X=Intv
lc <- t(sapply(l, colSums))
```

Sorry I noticed your sample data too late.

After you are done with the above example your next step would be to replace `*apply` functions with e.g. `par*apply` functions from the `snow` package to enhance procedure via parallelisation.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot. only issue is it should be rowSums, which I didn't explain clearly. i will change my code and get back to you when i know.

Comment: hi i got this error: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: intv was populated by reading csv file with header as true, giving it 16,385 rows to be exact. do you think that's the issue? output was an array with 16,384 rows by 200 columns. if so, any ideas how to fix it please?

Comment: check out the structure of `intv` via `str(object)`- using `read.csv`will usually return a data.frame - I would suggest you turn things into matrices e.g. via `as.matrix` - especially if you are gonna use `par*Apply` later on this will probably benefit you

Comment: its a data frame as you said. i ran this instead: > l <- lapply(X=as.matrix(intv), FUN=`<`, as.matrix(output)) and i got this: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 29.0 Mb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lapply(X = as.matrix(intv), FUN = `<`, as.matrix(output)) :
etc.. (too long to put here)

Comment: remainder of message: 2: In lapply(X = as.matrix(intv), FUN = `<`, as.matrix(output)) :
  Reached total allocation of 3583Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In lapply(X = as.matrix(intv), FUN = `<`, as.matrix(output)) :
  Reached total allocation of 3583Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In lapply(X = as.matrix(intv), FUN = `<`, as.matrix(output)) :
  Reached total allocation of 3583Mb: see help(memory.size)

Comment: aha 4gb limit - sound like 32 bit R ;-) ... 
first of all run the `as.matrix`before the lapply, remove all other/unnecessary objects from your workspace (e.g the data.frame versions of your data etc.) 
also check what version of R are you running?  try to get a hold of 64-bit - assuming you have a 64 bit machine available; how much RAM does your machine have? if you run into physical limits - check out bigmemory packages (but you will most probably loose speed/performance using these) if really everything fails - fire up a large Amazon AWS instance and run the code there ...

Comment: hi, thanks for all your help so far!! please see update above. it would be really interesting to figure out how to improve on the usual habit of for loops!

Comment: Perhaps, it might be more memory efficient to add the `rowSums` inside the first `lapply` to avoid creating a "list" with `nrow(intv)` replications of "output" matrix at a time.

Comment: hi again, changing all to matrix helped, a lott.

Comment: hi @alexis_laz ive looked into it a lot but i have no idea about the syntax, or where to even begin.. please help.

Comment: here is my desperate attempt @alexis_laz: > l <- lapply(X=Intvtrial, FUN='sum(Intvtrial<Outputtrial)', Outputtrial)
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'sum(Intvtrial<Outputtrial)' of mode 'function' was not found

Comment: @VarunSinha : Using your "intv" and "output", I mean something like `lapply(intv, function(x) rowSums(output >= x))`. That way the intermediate step of storing many matrices can be avoided.

Comment: @alexis_laz its hitting about 5 - 5.5 gb on 8 gb ram so far.. thanks a lot!